# Find the ratio of frequencies

Tags: waves

The figure illustrates the graphic of the resulting wave of two near frequency components as a function of time. Determine the ratio between the values ​​of the component frequencies ($\frac{f_{2}}{f_{1}}$, where $f_{2}> f_{1}$) from the graphic.

[image]

My attempt:

Consider

$$y(x, t) = a(x, t)cos(\overline{k}x - \overline{w}t)$$
where $a(x, t) = 2Acos(\frac{\Delta k}{2}x - \frac{\Delta \omega}{2}t)$

We have,

$$\frac{\Delta k}{2}x - \frac{\Delta \omega}{2}t_{1} = 0$$
$$\frac{\Delta k}{2}x - \frac{\Delta \omega}{2}t_{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Then,
$$\frac{\Delta \omega}{2}(t_{2} - t_{1}) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Thus,

$$\Delta f = -\frac{1}{6}$$

Observe that,

$$\frac{f_{1}}{f_{2}} = \frac{\overline f + \frac{1}{2}\Delta f}{\overline{f} - \frac{1}{2}\Delta f}$$

I can't find $\overline{f} = \frac{1}{2}(f_{1} + f_{2})$

Someone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Jaime -- please do not delete a question that is on hold and then repost it. If you have new information that you think would improve the question so it can be reopened, please edit it into the original question.Thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry! I didn't know how to proceed

Comment: No problem! When you edit the original, it will put it into a queue for users to review if it should be reopened or not. Edits automatically put it there, so make sure it follows the homework-and-exercises policy linked in the closed notice if you want others to vote to reopen!